# getting div content using javascript regex doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I got some html code as a response from an ajax call. And I want to get the content of a specific div. Here's the html:

```
<html>
     .
     .
   <div id="div-test">
          .
          .
   </div><!--/div-test-->
     .
     .
</html>
```

**Note**: I use the `<!--/div-test>` because `div#div-test` contains more divs.

And that's my regex:

```
/<div[^.]*id=\"div\-test\"[^.]*>(.*?)<\/div><\!\-\-\/div\-test\-\->/
```

But it doesn't work at all. When I try to match it, all I get is a `null` value. So, is my regex wrong or is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: append the response in jquery in a div fragment not appended to DOM and then using jQuery find out the 'dev-test'

Comment: Or if you're not using jQuery, create a [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) from the HTML first, and then search it...using a regex to find HTML tags is not reliable if there's any chance the HTML might change i.e. become more complex.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the regex :

```
<div[^>]*?id='div-test'[^>]*?>(.*?)<\/div><!--\/div-test-->
```

***Output***

[image]

Or if the makup is with `""` you can use

```
<div[^>]*?id=\"div-test\"[^>]*?>(.*?)<\/div><!--\/div-test-->
```

[image]

Comment: What about the `<!--/div-test-->` ? I need it, as I already said there some nested divs. Without the comment the regex match will fail.

Comment: hopefully he never uses `"` to denote the wrappings of the id attribute

Comment: Well I do use. And this example still gives me null even if I use \ on "

Comment: what if there's both `'` and `"` on the page? it's a pretty frequent thing in html. I'd highly suggest you don't use regex for simple checks like this that need to be taken into account. regex for html searching is generally a bad idea, on small scale it's not too bad, but it looks like you're getting a full html document

Comment: This doesnt call for recommendation, op was stuck with regex, so i gave the solution for the same... moreover there are more than one way of doing things

Comment: Should I stringify the ajax response before I do the regex match?

Comment: your regex is pretty strong, I didn't downvote it. whoever it was got me too XD

Comment: Ok another question. If I stringify the response it will then contain `\t`, `\r`, etc. How to replace them with `''`?

Comment: make another regex to replace them like `content.replace(/\t|\r/g,'');`

Comment: @TusharGupta i think it was failing for him because in order for your regex to work, the html needs to be in a single line. I think after he does that it'll work how he wants

Comment: Okay now replace doesn't remove \r and \n. Any idea why?

Comment: This is what I got now: `jsonResp = JSON.stringify(resp);` `jsonResp.replace(/\r|\t|\n/g, '');`

Comment: without doing the replace or stringify, try this regex: `<div[^>]*?id=[^\"]*?[^']*?div-test[^\"]*?[^']*?[^>]*?((?s).*)<\/div><!--\/div-test-->`

Comment: Okay it worked like this: `jsonResp = jsonResp.replace(/(?:\\[rn])+/g, '');` and then match this regex: `/<div[^>]*?id=\\\"div-test\\\"[^>]*?>(.*?)<\/div><\!--\/div-test-->/`

Comment: Or better: `jsonResp = jsonResp.replace(/(?:\\[rn])+/g, '');` then `jsonResp = jsonResp.replace(/\\*/g, '');` and then match: `/<div[^>]*?id=\"div-test\"[^>]*?>(.*?)<\/div><\!--\/div-test-->/`

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a non-regex approach, and you don't want to append the content on the page directly, you can create a document fragment and search through there:

```
var content = ""; // HTML FROM AJAX

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = content;
ajax_element = div.firstChild;
var test_content = ajax_element.getElementById('div-test').innerHTML;
```

as a regex approach, as much as I could advise against it, this might fit your needs:

```
var search_id = "div-test";
var r = new RegExp("<div[^>]*?id=[^\"]*?[^']*?"+search_id+"[^\"]*?[^']*?[^>]*?((?s).*)<\/div><!--\/"+search_id+"-->");
```

Comment: Since there is no reason to down vote this solution, will +1, And please whosoever is downvoting atleast give a reason

Comment: Perhaps somebody thought that the respondent explicitly suggested an approach that, yet obvious and useful, was not what the original poster asked for, even though we all know [about regex-parsing HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: @dakab i answered as asked `"And I want to get the content of a specific div."`, `"So, is my regex wrong or is there anything else I need to do?"`

Comment: First of all, I didn't downvoted. Yes I know I can do it without regex and yes I know parsing html using regex is not the best way. I just want to see why the regex from my question doesn't work. All answers are accepted and thanks, but I prefer a regex approach :)

Comment: @iam-decoder: I was just guessing the reason for the downvote. And true, the “anything else” part of the question opens it for other approaches! While I wouldn’t be afraid of HTML regexps, your `innerHTML` was the first thing that came to my mind too, to “get the content of a specific div”.

Comment: Yes it's true, the whole “anything else” thing was misleading.